# Define a delegate template with a Nullable data type

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to define a delegate  template(changeable input and output data type), something like this:

```
public delegate TOut? AB<TIn,out TOut>(TIn? a,TOot? b) where TIn:struct;
```

I just want to make the input and output value Nullable. This is the error I got:

Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1961  Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TResult' must be invariantly valid on 'Delegates.AopB.Invoke(TOperand?, TOperand?)'. 'TResult' is covariant.   Calculator

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public delegate TResult? AB<TOperand, TResult>(TOperand? a,TOperand? b) where TOperand:struct where TResult:struct;
```

Note that you cannot use `in` or `out` because variance can only happen with reference types, and `Nullable<T>` requires `T` be a value type.

Edit: Now that the question was edited, it definitely can't have `out` there because `out` won't work on a parameter except for `out` parameters. The answer now is:

```
public delegate TOut? AB<TIn, TOut>(TIn? a,TOut? b) where TIn:struct where TOut:struct;
```

Answer (score 1):

`TOut` cannot be marked with `out` unfortunately.

The following will work and is the closest you will get:

```
public delegate TOut? AB<TIn, TOut>(TIn? a,TOut? b) where TIn:struct where TOut:struct;
```